# Interpretation coefficients categorical variables

Tags: regression, least-squares, interpretation, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

I am working with a large panel dataset studying many companies over a long period of time. Some of these companies receive a negative outlook from an analyst during the sample period. Similarly, some of the companies receive a positive outlook from an analyst throughout the sample period. Many other companies do not receive any outlook.
I have estimated the following model, and am having a difficult time interpreting the coefficients:

$Dependent\_variable_{i,t}=Intercept+Large_{i}+Negative_{i}+Positive_{i}+Negative\_event_{i,t}+Positive\_event_{i,t}+Post\_Negative\_Event_{i,t}+Post\_Positive\_Event_{i,t}+Negative_{i}×Large_i+Positive_i×Large_i+Negative\_event_{i,t} \ ×Large_i+Positive\_event_{i,t}×Large_i+ Post\_Negative\_Event_{i,t}×Large_{i}+Post\_Positive\_Event_{i,t}×Large_{i}+Industry\_FE+Industry\_FE×Large_{i}+Controls_{i,t}+ϵ_{i,t}$

Description/definition of the independent variables:

1. $Large_i$ is equal to 1 for companies that have a large market capitalization, zero otherwise.
2. $Negative_i$ is equal to 1 for companies that (at some point during my sample period) receive a negative outlook from an analyst. Similar definition for $Positive_i$
3. $Negative\_event_{i,t}$ is equal to 1 during the 30 days after company $i$ experiences a downgrade (i.e. it is only 1 for that company $i$, not other companies). Similar definition for $Positive\_event_{i,t}$.
4. $Post\_Negative\_Event{i,t}$ is equal to 1 for the period **after** the 30 days (i.e. right after the end of the $Negative\_event_{i,t}$ period for company i) until the end of the sample period.

I've added dummy variables for the industry fixed effects, with Energy being the omitted industry. Additionally, I've added interactions between the Large indicator and the industry fixed effects.

Any help with interpretating the coefficients of this model would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you score your dependent variable? What form of regression did you use? What did you do about missing data?  And what does your output look like?

Comment: @PeterFlom The dependent variable is a continuous variable (some valuation metric of the company), and I used OLS to estimate the equation with clustered standard errors. There was no missing data.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have several binary explanatory variables, all of which are binary and enter the model either as simple main effects or a 2-way interaction.

For the coefficient of a main effect, where that variable is also in a two-way interaction, the coefficient represents the difference in the dependent variable between the variable being at 1 and being at 0, *when the variable that it is interacting with is at it's reference level*.

For the coefficient of a two-way interaction, this represents how the association between one variable and the dependent variable changes depending on the level of the other one.